# How to use User Default?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

Sorry if this is a newbie question, I am very new to iOS & Swift. I have seen already on the internet how to use User Default, but I don't know how to insert it in my project:

```
@IBOutlet weak var labelScore: UILabel!
var score = 0
let scoreUserDefault = UserDefaults.standard


@IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
    score += 1
    labelScore.text = String(score)
    print(score)
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let score = scoreUserDefault.value(forKey: "best") as? Int {
        self.score = score
    }
}
```

My project did not store the score, which I expected it to do.

Comment: you have to set the value after incrementing it. Btw you should use `integer(forKey:)` method to retrieve it.

Comment: whats the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to swift

// you should store value at first

// here also is good lesson for that part
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-save-user-settings-using-userdefaults

```
  @IBOutlet weak var labelScore: UILabel!
    var score = 0
    let scoreUserDefault = UserDefaults.standard


    @IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
        score += 1
        labelScore.text = String(score)

    //  you should store value  sta key
        scoreUserDefault.set(score, forKey: "best")


        print(score)
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let score = scoreUserDefault.integer(forKey: "best"){
            self.score = score
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Edoardo de Cal  check also above easy tutorial to learn more about that part

Comment: don't use value for key. use the proper method

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1407405-integer it does NOT return an optional. If the key value doesn't exits it returns zero. `score = scoreUserDefault.integer(forKey: "best")`